# Should we upgrade MySQL, move to PostgreSQL, or go cloud?

Tags: postgresql, cloud, mysql5.5

We use an internal MySQL 5.5 server for our ERP system.

#### Issue

- things are getting slow, and bosses are getting annoyed
- our SLA with our infrastructure service provider is ending soon.
- our small dev team will need to take over DB maintenance:

  - DB Clustering
  - DB Backups
  - DB Crash Recovery

#### Shortfalls:

- DB is not normalized
- DB is MyISAM (no row-level locking, so calls get super slow)
- DB is 228533.13 MB
- our ERP software is:

  - PHP
  - huge
  - badly written
  - no DB abstraction layer
  - business logic is embedded in SQLs

#### Goals in order of importance

1. remove reliance on service provider
2. migrate to cloud or make ready to migrate
3. minimize business risk
4. make maintainable
5. make fast
6. minimize crappiness for dev team

#### Approaches we can think of

We're weighing the pros and cons of:

- switching to PostgreSQL
- upgrading MySQL
- move to some cloud-based service
- looking for a magic solution we don't know about yet

#### Help requested

Can you guys comment?  We're in the investigation phase and want to make the right decision moving forward for a good few years.

Jokes and jibes at our plight are expected and encouraged. ^^

Comment: Interesting question but FYI - it'll probably get closed due to "primarily opinion-based. I don't have an answer, but moving to cloud almost certainly won't solve your problems. Cloud is not a magic bullet, even if there is provider that supports 5.5 it's still going to be same old and buggy code.

Comment: Thanks.  Code improvement is ongoing.  The thinking now is to do new stuff with Phalcon models, and slowly refactor old stuff.

The pressure is on right now simply because one ledger table that's core to a lot of business logic is getting massive, slow and having business impact.

Our initial solution was to upgrade 5.5 to 5.6 and switch to innodb to enable row locking.  Our provider said they have no backup experience with innodb, and an upgrade breaks contract. They're pushing us to migrate to Postgres.

So, it's risk tennis match.

We want to reduce busy work and do what's right.

Comment: Idealist in me says migration to Postgres is the right idea. Realist suggests that even 5.5 -> 5.6 may be PITA. If you are under time pressure you may consider running 5.5 yourself on top of sever with quick IO system (e.g. some fast NVMe SSD) while you slowly consider your options.

Answer (score 0):

My first advice would be improving software but i guess you are already doing it or it's a no go. I would suggest scaling. Add 1 or 2 more servers, change a few lines of code and voila, you have 3 primary MySQL servers.

Answer (score 0):

It is question of resources: domain knowledge (DBA, sysadmin), money and time.

Since you have to refactor app, try to outsource DB and server maintenance, at least until you have time to handle it yourself. Go with cloud DB provider or buy new HW and outsource DBA/sysadmin.

With slow DB, brute force fix is using SSD disks and more RAM.

Is PHP version 7.2+? Latest version has significant performance improvement.

Use caching in PHP app, eg. memcache.

Last but first, find bottleneck.

DB write? Faster disk, InnoDB or Postgres

DB read? Index, rewrite query, cache results

DB temp tables? Add RAM to DB

Slow SQL query? Rewrite it, add index

CPU? PHP upgrade, rewrite SQL query, stronger server